# discord.py How to use loops

Tags: discord.py

```
async def kick(ctx):
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(1066518590813118494)
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
      if role in member.roles:
          await member.kick(reason='Test')
```

I want to loop this phrase
I want to be banished after holding a certain role for a certain period of time.
I've been studying iterative statements, but it's difficult to understand.
Please understand that I am using a translator due to my lack of English.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html). You can have a task looping every **X INTERVAL** and then during that interval, check if a user needs removing from a particular role. If your bot is the one assigning the role in the first place; then you could store the time that role was assigned in a data structure somewhere (like a dict, list, whatever), in a file locally, or in a database. You can then use that in the task to do the check to see if a user needs their role removing.